# How to improve TCP/IP server scalability when restricted by application thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP/IP server written in C# .net which can have 10,000 connections at once easy. However, when a callback is received from a socket, it is dealt with by a new thread in the application thread pool. This means that the real concurrent communication limitation is down to the number of threads within the thread pool. For example if those 10,000 connections all attempt to send data at the same time, the majority will have to wait whilst the thread pool runs through as fast as it can. Can anyone share their experience with high performance socket services and advise how a large corporation would go about ensuring the 10,000 connections can not only be connected at the same time, but can also communicate at the same time? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't process the packets inline in the callback.  Do the absolute minimum work there, and then hand them off to a separate worker thread pool via a producer-consumer queue that (ideally) never blocks the producer threads, which are your socket listeners.  [BlockingCollection`<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) may be useful here.

You have to be careful that the queue does not grow unbounded - if your consumers are a lot slower than producers, and the queue grows under normal load, you have a problem to which throttling the network receives is the obvious solution, despite its undesirability.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, you advise not to process packets inline in the callback; what I am doing is using asynchronous sockets and my function is effectively as follows, can you confirm that this is suitable according to your suggestion? thanks.. private void receiveClientCallback(IAsyncResult result){SocketConnection client = (SocketConnection)result.AsyncState;client.EndReceive(result);System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new ConnectionHandler(this, client).ThreadPoolCallback);}

Comment: Broadly that's the idea. Suitability in practice depends on who else is using the process `ThreadPool`. Using your own queue and thread pool would give you tighter control - on the `ThreadPool` you are competing with other 'stuff' and should understand what that is in your system, to know if you should use a private pool.  Tuning the `ThreadPool` parameters might be all you need.

Comment: The thread pool is soley reserved for the connection handler threads, which only make a couple of database queries and then save specific packet contents to a file, which another service picks up and processes in its own thread pool

Comment: Sounds like you can party on then.  Virtualizing this would bother me though.  Try to benchmark on real hardware in case you need evidence of degradation in VM.

Answer (score 1):

YOu make a thought mistake here. Regardless how many thread you have, data always has to wait unless you have one CPU CORE PER CONNECTION. Scalability is not having unlimited paralellism, but being ab le to handle a lot of conenctions and keep the cpu at full power.

The thread pool is perfectly sized for that. Once the CPU reaches full utilization, you can not do anything else anyway.

> and advise how a large corporation would go about ensuring the 10,000 connections can not only be 
>   connected at the same time, but can also communicate at the same time?

MANY computers that have like a total of 500 processor cores. The trick is: what latency is acceptable. You dont need instant communication. You try to sovle that from the wrong end.

Comment: Thanks TomTom, you appear to clarify what I was thinking, which was this has to be as good as it gets, there isn't really any other way to improve on this now, from here on it must be down to the hardware. I have an 8 core laptop which can accept 10,000 connections in a matter of seconds, however if those connections then go on to send an authentication packet, which results in a thread querying the database, and they then go on to transfer 3kb of data, it takes an overall time of 7mins to accept, authenticate, then accept the 3kb packet from the 10,000 connections

Comment: I am worried because the virtual private server we are going to run this server on only has 1 gig of ram and 1 core. If we were to increase the VPS to 8 core, and it still take 7 mins to accept 3kb from 10,000 connections, well, i guess we will need several servers, each running several copies of the service, to handle this amount of connections.

Comment: Oh dear, your bean counters want to virtualize your system?  Sounds like a bad idea for this config.  You are right to be worried imo.

Comment: Yes. Get a SERVER. If you have to do that load, you dont virtualize. You get a REAL server, 24 core upward and see how that deals with it.